# .NET Debug continues after breaking stopping

Tags: .net, debugging

I use breakpoints in Visual Studio when debugging.  Have a look at the following code:

```
Try
   Dim Test1 As String
   Throw New Exception
Catch ex As Exception
   Msg("test")
End Try
```

I have noticed that if I place a breakpoint on line 2 (where Test1 is declared) and then stop the program (by pressing the stop button), a message box will appear saying Test.  How can a message box appear if the program has stopped? This is a very simple example.  It usually happens when the code is a lot more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Although you'd expect to be able to, you generally can't breakpoint the declaration of a variable because the compiler adds it to the locals of the generated method's IL and it becomes part of the method's stack preparation.  In effect, by the time the method runs the variable is already declared.

Hence the exception raising is actually the first thing that runs.

As @sixlettervariables has then said, if you *assign* the variable then it's different, because that's user code that is part of the method body.

Answer (score 0):

You should see it in a different way, rather than on a par line basis.

The debugger allows you to include instructions that freeze the execution of the program. 
But because you are only declaring a variable, there is no way to freeze the program at this moment.

Indeed, the variable is  already declared before you "hit" that line.

The next place where it will  be able to freeze the program is on the next instruction (and not declaration). Your next instruction is `Msg("test")`

Comment: I have stopped the program on line 3 (instead of line 2) and it happens again.